# Lake Formation sharing with external account - error when querying with athena in target account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-lake-formation, data-mesh

I have two accounts, the source account (A) and the target account (B)

I have granted account (B) access to a database in account (A) via lakeformation.

In account B I accepted the resource share and can see the database and table populated in the lake formation console.

In account B I have created a resource link and granted access to my user with permissions (SUPER)

In account B when I try to query the table within the database resource link I get the following error

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied
> (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
> Request ID: ##########; S3 Extended Request ID: ########; Proxy:
> null), S3 Extended Request ID: ########### (Bucket: {Bucket in account
> A that holds shared database and tables}, Key: {path to shared table})
> This query ran against the "{resource link database}" database, unless
> qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or
> contact customer support  with Query Id: ##############

My account is a lake formation admin with administrator access.

The data catalogue settings in account A & B are;

Use only IAM access control for new databases:  OFF
Use only IAM access control for new tables in new databases: OFF
Version 4

The error is showing some access denied on my S3 resource in Account A that is shared, but I do not understand how this error can come up with the above settings?

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried changing the settings - changing location of the shared table - changing the accesses on the databases for my user.

Answer (score 0):

Check few things:

1. Verify if lake formation role have access to S3 bucket and KMS key if data is encrypted
   [image]
2. Verify if your table have location configured
   [image]